# How to use wsdl2phpgenerator on WAMP

Tags: php, wsdl

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to get the php for a soap wsdl request working. I came across wsdl2phpgenerator which sounds like it generates the code for the service you want? Problem is I can't figure out how to use it. I'm running WAMP on my local machine. How do i install and use, the instruction don't seem to make a lot of sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you use windows when you use WAMP.
You should not run the wsdl2phpgenerator through apache. You need to run it on the commandline.

step 1:
First open the CMD and type:

```
php --version
```

If the cmd prints something out like :

```
PHP 5.4.19 (cli) (built: Aug 23 2013 00:51:43) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
```

go to step 3:

step 2: add php to windows env path:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9546345/1210773
use the path to your own php installation
after this run step 1 to validate php is correctly setup

Step3: run wsdl2phpgenerator
move the cmd to the wsdl2phpgenerator dir and run wsdl2php

I found some examples in the wsdl2phpgenerator documentation:
https://github.com/wsdl2phpgenerator/wsdl2phpgenerator/wiki/ExampleUsage

Comment: hey thanks for this, think I got it working. i was hoping it would add the headers as well for authentication, but doesn't seem to?

Comment: I think you are correct about that. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4393535/1210773 , shows how this works. you can add it to the client